# How do I get default Developer Console output date format?

Tags: visualforce, datetime, string

I'm trying to get the DateTime field values formatted to example below which is the Developer Console Query editor output.

e.g.

2017-01-04T06:00:00.000+0000

But when I used String.valueOf(datetimeToConvert) it gives a different format.

e.g.

2017-01-04 06:00:00

Is there a way to get it as a formatted string? without forced formatting? Also I wonder why those right padding zeros, char 'T', etc.
Appreciate any help on this conversion. Thanks.

Comment: Char 'T', 'Z' and padding zeros specifies the time zone in the date format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON to serialize:

```
Account a = [Select CreatedDate From Account LIMIT 1];
System.debug(json.serialize(a.CreatedDate));
```

Or with string formatting:

```
System.debug(a.createdDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'));
```

> 02:28:12.31 (39198321)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|"2016-11-07T15:59:57.000Z"
>
> 02:28:12.31 (39316094)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|2016-11-07T10:59:57.000-05:00